# Plone: access permission on a add-on package

Tags: plone, configure, zope, user-permissions, zcml

I'm new on Plone and I'm developing a small add-on package.

How can I define a permission so that only logged users can access to the pages of the package?

The actual permission is the following:

```
<browser:page
 name="homepage"
 for="*"
 permissions="zope.View"
 class=".homepage.HomepageView"
 />
```

With the standard permissions="zope.View" the page is accessible from everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create your own permission or use an existing permission that is only granted to registered users by default, e.g. the "cmf.SetOwnPassword" permission:

```
<browser:page
  name="homepage"
  for="*"
  permission="cmf.SetOwnPassword"
  class=".homepage.HomepageView"
/>
```

Comment: Of course, for any re-used permission, somebody comes along and finds a counterexample – I'm not sure if members still have, or should have, `Set own password` if they authenticate against LDAP, AD, Shibboleth, or whatever. I'd be tempted to go with `Portlets: View dashboard`, and now you're welcome to point out a counterexample for that ;)